# How can I return two views from an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionresult, viewresult

How can I return two views from an action?

I tried as below but I got an error.

```
public ActionResult Page()
{
    //LINQ x expressions
    //LINQ y expressions
    if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "x")
    {
        return View(linqExpX.ToList());
    }
    else if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "y")
    {
        return View(linqExpY.ToList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all parts of your code return a value..

Try this code:

```
public ActionResult Page()
{
    //LINQ x expressions
    //LINQ y expressions
    if(Request.QueryString["type"] == "x")
    {
        return View(linqExpX.ToList());
    }
    else if(Request.QueryString["type"] == "y")
    {
        return View(linqExpY.ToList());
    }

    return someDefaultView; 
}
```

Comment: return View(Request.QueryString["type"] == "x" ? linqExpX.ToList() : linqExpY.ToList());